# beautifulsoup can't get 'tr' in table

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-table

I'm trying to get a list of company names (e.g. 01Venture) and types (e.g. GENERAL PATERNER) from this website https://www.bvca.co.uk/Member-Directory. I'm using the code below:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
URL = 'https://www.bvca.co.uk/Member-Directory'
page = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
print(soup.prettify())

table = soup.find('table', attrs={'id':'searchresults'})
table_body = table.find('tbody')
rows = table_body.find_all('tr')

print(rows)
```

And I got an empty list.

Comment: Is loaded dynamically. Use network tab to see where data is really coming from (additional xhr) or use selenium

Comment: you may have to use selenium to get the source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `selenium` package, you will need to install `chromedriver`.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

URL = 'https://www.bvca.co.uk/Member-Directory'

BrowserOptions = Options()
BrowserOptions.add_argument("--headless")
Browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'chromedriver.exe', options=BrowserOptions)
Browser.get(URL)
while True:
    if Browser.find_elements_by_class_name('companyName'):
        break
    
html_source_code = Browser.execute_script("return document.body.innerHTML;")

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_source_code, 'html.parser')

x = [r.text for r in soup.find_all('h5',class_='companyName')]
print(x)

>>> ['01 Ventures', '01 Ventures', '17Capital LLP', '17Capital LLP', '1818 Venture Capital', ..., 'Zouk Capital LLP', 'Zouk Capital LLP']
```

The while loop waits until the company names are loaded before the html code is saved

The output was too large to put into the answer, so I could only show some of it.